# create_user not returning full user object of the newly created user

Tags: django

I am doing simply:

```
      user = User.objects.create_user(**data)
      print(user['id']) # user.pk
```

dont work. If i do print(user), I see username of the newly added user. Is there a way to return the user id along with first_name? Or must I query the model with the user name to get user details of the newly added user?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Just try like this: `print(user.first_name)`

Comment: or, just use **`print(user.__dict__)`** get ar dict rep of the user

Comment: @ruddra it works for first_name but notice my question is about getting pk or id of the user